# How does the migration process handle the post dates

Tags: discussion, migration, dates

It appears that when a question is migrated between sites,  it keeps the original dates.  Is it possible to add a date on the "Migrated from X" message?  It is a little odd to see messages asked on Sept 19, 2008 in SuperUser for example.    How does the date affect the date related badges like Neocramcer?

Answer (score 2):

Migration apparently keeps the original ask date. Perhaps when it's migrated, it should be reset as it's now born again but on the proper site?

As for the Necromancer badge, it was possible during the [Beta period for a couple of Necromancer badges to fall out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6253/superuser-you-won-necromancer) of the SOFU pockets.