# Inconsistent definitions of account start date

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, superuser, reputation-leagues

In the Stack Exchange [Reputation Leagues for Super User](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/year/superuser), [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/users/26316/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) is listed as a "user for 7 months", and has 13k+ rep for the year, but he isn't listed at the top of the "Top New Users" list on the right.

It seems like in some places, calculations are based on when the account was first created or first had a question migrated in from elsewhere, but in other places, it's based on when the user started actually posting from the account?

Over in SU chat we figured out that maybe he had a [migrated question in 2008](https://superuser.com/questions/118468/how-do-you-change-the-password-for-the-keyring-manager-in-ubuntu/118471#118471) (!? Before SU existed?) that he never "claimed" (never created/linked his accounts), and then perhaps he finally created his account in 2010?

Comment: Migrated questions retain their original post dates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17716/how-does-the-migration-process-handle-the-post-dates/17719#17719

Comment: @Popular Demand that's a useful data point, but just to be clear, you don't mean to imply that that artifact excuses calculating the account's start date differently in different places, do you?

Comment: no, no excuse. That comment is solely an explanation for "(!? Before SU existed?)" and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does indeed appear to be a migrated question dating to before his account was created.  I clearly neglected to take into account that users can earn rep before they exist :)

We should have a fix later today.

**Update** The fix is deployed.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks @David Fullerton. (and @Diago and others who helped figure this out over in SU chat.)