# A migrated question's "newness" should be based on when it was migrated

Tags: feature-request, migration, migrated-questions, new-questions

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775904/putting-a-tableview-on-a-viewcontroller) was on the Programmers.SE for a day or so without any answers.  So, I answered it.  Not long after that, it was migrated to SO.  I was surprised to find that it was not located on the first several pages after being migrated.  It seems that it's [placement is based on when the question was *asked* instead of of when it was *migrated*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17716/how-does-the-migration-process-handle-the-post-dates).

A large reason for putting new questions at the top of the list is so that enthusiastic answerers can jump at the ones that interest them right out of the gate.  However, a question that's migrated is nearly hidden from these most eager answerers, because the question jumps immediately to a sad page that is normally full of questions that people have either answered or deliberately passed over.

**Should newly-migrated questions get a chance at being displayed prominently along with their newly-posted counterparts?**

**EDIT:** To be clear, I am not asking what the current behavior is (which has already been asked and answered in another question). I am asking if the current behavior best serves the SO community.

Comment: This sounds more like a feature request than a duplicate of "how the date in migrated questions works".

Comment: That question states what I have stated, but it does not answer what I am asking.  I am asking the community (with a discussion flag) if this behavior should be modified.  With this in mind, please consider reopening this question.

Comment: If something should be modified, that could be a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the current setup works fine.

The Questions page has several different sorts. The "newest" is powered by when the question was asked, and this still applies to migrated questions. The "active" sort (which powers the homepage on all sites except Stack Overflow), predictably enough, goes by the last activity date. Migration counts as an activity, so migrated questions appear in the appropriate place on that list and on the site's homepage.

The net effect is that when a question is migrated, it gets the same homepage/activity placement as it would if it had just been asked.